# Trying to Identify this surface mount component marked 'J4S' on top

Tags: identification

[image]

This is from the speed sensor circuit for a 1995 era Toyota Rav 4.

I have googled and the only thing close I get is a Schottky Diode.

Can anybody help?

Thanks,

Meric.

Comment: Thermal fuse or similar sometimes look like this. Can you trace out some of the connection components?

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Original-New-Schottky-Barrier-Diode-F2J4STP-F2J4S-SMC-DO-214AB-Marking-J4S/32350175433.html